# How to Loop for each Recordset in ASP

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I need help with loop, I'm trying to create a Menu with a submenu, In my DataBase i have a table named tblMenu which have five fields (**link_position**, **link**, **link_name**, **link_title**, **sub_menu**)

**link_position** field is for sorting the menu Item's position,

**link** field stores the link for menu Item,

**link_name** holds the Name for Menu Item,

**link_title** holds the link title for Menu Item,

**sub_menu** stores the Sub Items (Dropdown) for the Menu.

**Here is the preview of tblMenu**

[image]

**Here is the Code for Loop**

```
<ul>
<%
msql = "SELECT * FROM tblMenu ORDER BY [link_position] ASC"
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set RSsub = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open msql, Conn, 1,3
SET RSsub = Conn.execute ("SELECT * FROM tblMenu ORDER BY [link_position] ASC")

If Not RS.EOF Then
Do
Response.Write("<li><a href=""" & RS("link") & """ title =""" & RS("link_title") & """>" & RS("link_name") & "</a>" & vbcrlf)

            If Not RSsub.EOF Then
                Response.Write("<ul class=""sub-menu"">" & vbcrlf)
                Do While Not RSsub.EOF
                    Response.Write(RSsub("sub_menu") & vbcrlf)
                    RSsub.MoveNext()
                Loop
                Response.Write "</ul>" & vbcrlf
            End If
'                RSsub.Close

                Response.Write("</li>" & vbcrlf)
                RS.MoveNext()

        Loop Until RS.EOF
    End If          
%>
</ul>
```

**The Output**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/asp/" title ="Main Page">Home</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">

<li><a href="#">Inquiry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Inquiry2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ELS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">AP</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=1" title ="About us">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=2" title ="E-Learning System">E-Learning</a></li>
<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=5" title ="Academic Policies">Academic Policies</a></li>
<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=6" title ="Facilities">Facilities</a></li>
<li><a href="/asp/events.asp" title ="Events Gallery">Events</a></li>

</ul>
```

**The Problem**

The loop for sub_menus throws all Records under first Recordset of the Main loop, the output im expecting should be like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/asp/" title ="Main Page">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=1" title ="About us">About</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">Inquiry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Inquiry2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=2" title ="E-Learning System">E-Learning</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">ELS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=5" title ="Academic Policies">Academic Policies</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">AP</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/asp/page.asp?pID=6" title ="Facilities">Facilities</a></li>
<li><a href="/asp/events.asp" title ="Events Gallery">Events</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you run the same query two times. It seems like you have all information you want from the first SQL. If I understood your question correct this code is both simpler and faster.

```
<%
msql = "SELECT link_position, link, link_name, link_title, IIF(IsNull(sub_menu),'',sub_menu) as sub_menu FROM tblMenu ORDER BY [link_position] ASC"
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open msql, Conn, 1,3

If Not RS.EOF Then
    response.write "<ul>"
    Do
        Response.Write("<li><a href='" & RS("link") & "' title ='" & RS("link_title") & "'>" & RS("link_name") & "</a>" & vbcrlf)

        If Not trim(RS("sub_menu")) = "" Then
            Response.Write("<ul class='sub-menu'>" & vbcrlf)
            Response.Write(RS("sub_menu") & vbcrlf)
            Response.Write "</ul>" & vbcrlf
        End If
        Response.Write("</li>" & vbcrlf)
        RS.MoveNext()
    Loop Until RS.EOF
    response.write "</ul>"
End If          
%>
```

Comment: @SearchAndResQ encountered this error `Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E14)
Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'IsNull(sub_menu,'')'.`

Comment: MS Access `isnull` is different from MSSQL. you have to use `iif` and `isnull` together : IIF(IsNull(sub_menu),'',sub_menu) as sub_menu`

Comment: @David thank you for helping me out, i'm really a beginner in asp SearchAndResQ is the witness. Thank you guys you are awesome ;)